# How to include phtml file using ajax or jQuery or javascript?

Tags: magento2, layout

I tried,

```
 function chk_val()
 {
     var buy_now = '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/buy_now.phtml")->toHtml();?>';
     jQuery('#div_buy_now').html(buy_now);

}
```

Getting output as :

```
   getLayout()->createBlock("MagentoFrameworkViewElementTemplate")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/buy_now.phtml")->toHtml();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where you have placed this function ? if you directly print this in phtml output is coing ?

Comment: @PankajPareek - yes, if I put directly file gets included but I want to call that file using ajax

Comment: where you have placed this function ?

Comment: app\design\frontend\Nest\test\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

Comment: code should work if it is directly print then. can you check in console for buy_now variable

Comment: @PankajPareek - I have attached screenshot

Comment: @PankajPareek - I have put one more screenshot

Comment: Yes phtml code using block is not coming script tag

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to give you an example about Ajax:

Define the routes:

app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="ajaxtest" frontName="ajaxtest">
            <module name="Vendor_AjaxTest" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The purpose of next five files is to add the template which contains the Ajax script.

1) app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AjaxTest\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

2) app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/view/frontend/layout/ajaxtest_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\AjaxTest\Block\Index" name="ajax.test.index"
                   template="Vendor_AjaxTest::index.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3) app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/Block/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AjaxTest\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;;

class Index extends Template
{

}
```

Here is the template to add the Js. I used `data-mage-init` to initialize our script.

4) app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml

```
<h2>
    <?php echo __('Ajax Test'); ?>
</h2>

<div class="ajax-test" data-mage-init='{"Vendor_AjaxTest/js/ajax-block" :
{"ajaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('ajaxtest/index/content') ?>"}}'>
</div>
```

5) Our custom js script, it should be simple

app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/view/frontend/web/js/ajax-block.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function (config, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: config.ajaxUrl,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(element).html(data['html']);
        })
    }
});
```

Now, we need to define the ajax controller - `ajaxtest/index/content`

app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/Controller/Index/Content.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AjaxTest\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Content extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonHelper
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $httpBadRequestCode = 400;
        //Check isXmlHttpRequest
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->jsonFactory->create()->setHttpResponseCode($httpBadRequestCode);
        }

        $html = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Vendor\AjaxTest\Block\Content'
        )->toHtml();
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData(['html' => $html]);
    }
}
```

In our controller, we create a custom block- `Vendor\AjaxTest\Block\Content`, and set its content to json response.

app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/Block/Content.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AjaxTest\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Content extends Template
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_AjaxTest::content.phtml';
}
```

app/code/Vendor/AjaxTest/view/frontend/templates/content.phtml

```
<?php echo __('Testing block!');
```

Remember to create the module.xml and registration.

In the browser, try to run `http://{base_url}/ajaxtest/index/index`, you will see the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have gone through your code and its working fine. I have little modification in code. Actually in Estimate Calculator Button I will call ajax and then only Buy Now Button will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah! I only give you an Ajax example.

Comment: Ajax is getting called properly but Buy Now button is not functioning. I think because of data-mage-init='
    {
    "Test_ServiceDetail/js/buy-now": {
    "form": "#product_addtocart_form"
  }
}
'

Comment: Yes, You should write your own Ajax script. There are many good examples from core Magento, ex: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

Comment: This is the best example I was able to find anywhere, and helped me out perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @jassi I am facing the same issue, Buy Now button redirects me to the controller url with parameter as in the example used for fetching block using ajax, how can I avoid that and make my Buy Now button work like before?

Comment: @Nausif my example just showed how to implement the Ajax. So, in this case, we need to build your own logic. You should write your own Ajax script: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`